# Bounding rectangle around object opencv.js throwing error in console

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am finding object from an image with opencv.js library . not able to draw a rectangle around the funded object

I already tried the following code block

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasInput');
        canvas.renderImage(e.target.files[0]);
        let src = cv.imread("canvasInput");
        let dst = cv.Mat.zeros(src.rows, src.cols, cv.CV_8UC3);
        cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
        cv.threshold(src, src, 177, 200, cv.THRESH_BINARY);
        let contours = new cv.MatVector();
        let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();
        cv.findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        let cnt = contours.get(0);
        let rect = cv.boundingRect(cnt);
        let contoursColor = new cv.Scalar(255, 255, 255);
        let rectangleColor = new cv.Scalar(255, 0, 0);
        cv.drawContours(dst, contours, 0, contoursColor, 1, 8, hierarchy, 100);
        let point1 = new cv.Point(rect.x, rect.y);
        let point2 = new cv.Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
        cv.rectangle(dst, point1, point2, rectangleColor, 2, cv.LINE_AA, 0);
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
        src.delete(); dst.delete(); contours.delete(); hierarchy.delete(); 
         cnt.delete();
```

### but finding

opcv.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$' of undefined
    at RegisteredPointer.nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType [as toWireType] (opcv.js:21)
    at Object.boundingRect (eval at new_ (opcv.js:21), :7:26)
    at HTMLInputElement.inputElement.addEventListener (openCv.php:52)
nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType @ opcv.js:21
boundingRect @ VM24025:7

### inputElement.addEventListener @ openCv.php:52

error in console.

Answer (score 0):

This error will be raised when the `findContours` output value `contours` has 0 elements, thus dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

in your code,

```
<br>
let cnt = contours.get(0);
<br>
```

## cnt has not get any contours then opencv.js file not implement the return to contours zero then it give that error

```
<br>
(opcv.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$' of undefined at RegisteredPointer.nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType [as toWireType] (opcv.js:21) at Object.boundingRect (eval at new_ (opcv.js:21), :7:26) at HTMLInputElement.inputElement.addEventListener (openCv.php:52) nonConstNoSmartPtrRawPointerToWireType @ opcv.js:21 boundingRect @ VM24025:7)
```

**the solution is use another image or look any plane image return in your code,do not use plane images**